# How do I rerun Activities in Continuum when there is a network failure?

Tags: versionone, continuum

I have an activity in Continuum that points to some automated tests that sometimes fail. The failures are usually network related, and not related to an actual problem. So in this cases, I'd love to be able to automatically rerun (or at least rerun them manually) and make that trigger the "Success" in my progression so that I can continue the workflow. Another user here recently and gave me the impression that was possible, but I cannot figure out how. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated "activities" are simply triggers to pipelines, and pipelines can be re-started in the same context as they were originally executed.

Drill into the failed activity, and at the top of the pipeline instance page by the status indicator, there is a "play" button.

[image]

The failure of an activity is an important event, so there's no way to configure the activity to "retry" automatically.  However, depending on what your *pipeline* is actually doing, it may be possible for you to add some resiliency *inside* the pipeline logic, to help with network hiccups.